# What is the impact of the ^ character in symfony firewall?

Tags: php, symfony, security, firewall

I see in the sample config for the Symfony firewall (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) that routes should be specified thusly

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

But I have been doing it for quite a while without the ^ character. What does it do?

So this config seems to achieve the same thing:

```
access_control:
    - { path: /admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: /profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: The path is a regex, so, it has the same meaning as in a regex: _matches the start of a string without consuming any characters_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the documantation:

> Prepending the path with ^ means that only URLs beginning with the pattern are matched. For example, a path of /admin (without the ^) would match /admin/foo but would also match URLs like /foo/admin.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default restriction and restricts a firewall to only be initialized if the request path matches the configured pattern.

"The pattern is a regular expression. In this example, the firewall will only be activated if the path starts (due to the ^ regex character) with /admin. If the path does not match this pattern, the firewall will not be activated and subsequent firewalls will have the opportunity to be matched for this request."

Reference: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html

Comment: And with that in mind, I should up and add that ^ character to the beginning of every rule in my firewall... 